# Using wildcards in spark.jars when submitting Apache Spark jobs

Tags: apache-spark

I have a set of JARs I want to make available to my Spark jobs, stored on HDFS.

The documentation for Spark 2.3 says that `spark.jars` is the parameter for that:

`spark.jars: Comma-separated list of jars to include on the driver and executor classpaths. Globs are allowed.`

However, setting `spark.jars` to `hdfs:///path/to/my/libs/*.jar` fails: the driver starts up OK, a stage is kicked off, but then tasks die with:

`WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, xxxx, executor 1): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File hdfs:/path/to/my/libs/*.jar does not exist.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listStatusInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:901)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchHcfsFile(Utils.scala:724)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:692)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:472)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:755)
...`

i.e., it did not expand the glob when running on the executor it seems.

Explicitly setting `spark.jars` to `hdfs:///path/to/my/libs/libA.jar,hdfs:///path/to/my/libs/libB.jar` does work correctly.

How can I use glob, as indicated by the documentation, in `spark.jars`?

Comment: Too bad you didn't get an answer to this because I'm experiencing and wondering the same thing. I will research more and post a reply if I find a glob syntax that works.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with full paths. The glob pattern is processed by HDFS FileSystem::globStatus doing the processing.  Spark passes in their HadoopConfig.  This doesn't seem to work on full paths though.  Spark's test code uses simple patterns, "*one.jar", for example, not paths.

Ref: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#globStatus(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.PathFilter)

Spark Commit, ref resolveGlobPaths: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/18235/files#diff-f8564df81d845c0cd2f621bc2ed22761cbf9731f28cb2828d9cbd0491f4e7584

Answer (score -1):

I am running all spark batch and streaming application from local file system. I am not sure why there is need of storing them on hdfs.

But if you prefer to use local file system to save your jar then you can use wildcard as below : -

```
export BASE_DIR="/local/file/path/where/jar/is/available"

spark-submit \
    --class ${class} \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --master yarn \
...
...
...
    --name ${APPLICATION_NAME} \
    ${BASE_DIR}/*.jar
```

Hope this is helpful.